# How can I setup password renewal emails using Firebase?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have setup a IBAction button so that once selected, a UIAlertController containing a text field appears, allowing a user to enter their email. Once this email has been entered and "submit" has been selected, an email should be sent to the "answer" value, however it doesn't seem to be sending any emails during testing. How can I get this working properly?

```
@IBAction func forgottenPassword(_ sender: Any) {

        let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Your account email", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
        ac.addTextField()

        let submitAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Submit", style: .default) { [unowned ac] _ in
            let answer = ac.textFields![0]
           
                Auth.auth().sendPasswordReset(withEmail: "\(answer)") { error in
                
                }
            }
        
        ac.addAction(submitAction)

        present(ac, animated: true)      
       
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clue is that you have used `"\(answer)"`, presumably because the compiler was complaining that a `UITextField` is not a `String`.

`ac.textFields` is an array of `UITextField`.  You need to access the `text` property of the `UITextField` to get the string it holds.  Also, this is an optional string (although in practice it will typically be an empty string (`""`) rather than `nil` if the text field is empty).

You can use optional chaining with a conditional unwrap to get the value and avoid the force unwrapping:

```
@IBAction func forgottenPassword(_ sender: Any) {
        
    let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Your account email", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
    ac.addTextField()
        
    let submitAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Submit", style: .default) { _ in
        if let answer = ac.textFields?.first?.text {
            Auth.auth().sendPasswordReset(withEmail: answer) { error in
                    // TODO: Handle a non-nil error.
            }
        }
    }
        
    ac.addAction(submitAction)
        
    present(ac, animated: true)
        
}
```

Comment: Thanks @paulw11 - I am getting a "variable used within its own initial value" error for the - ac.addAction(submitAction) - line though.

Comment: Sorry, there was a } missing.  Also, you don't need the `[unowned ac]` - You can't create a leak from a local alert view controller.

Comment: No worries @paulw11 - even when I add a closing } I get the following error "Value of optional type '[UITextField]?' must be unwrapped to refer to member 'first' of wrapped base type '[UITextField]'" for the - ac.textFields.first?.text - line. Am I correct in believing I need to unwrap it first? I'm not too sure how I would go about doing that.

Comment: Sorry, missing a ?

Comment: Where would the "?" need to go?

Comment: I already added it to my answer. `if let answer = ac.textFields?.first?.text`

Comment: Really appreciate your help! I've added in the code, tested it out with my personal email but I haven't had anything come through after waiting like 30 minutes. Is there anything I need to configure from the Firebase console?

Comment: That I don't know. I don't use firebase. Did you check the `error` response from `sendPasswordReset`?

Comment: I added `print("test")` after the `error in` line to see if anything was being outputted and in the debug area it is printing out "test". So it just seems as though it is always encountering errors and previously it had nothing to run, but now I can use the print("test") to output something. I still haven't had any emails come through either.

Comment: Rather than `print(test)` how about `print(error)`? or `if let error = error { print(error) } else { print("OK") }`

Comment: I got it working now, turns out I was trying to reset a password and I was entering an email address and as there wasn't a user with the entered email address in the database it was returning an error. Thank you so much for your help and dedication, can I DM you please? I'd like to buy you a coffee to say thank you! :)